# How does continuity implies closeness

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was reading a [proof](https://www.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/notes/nlp/unoc.pdf) [Theorm 1.2], there says the continuity of the function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ implies the closedness of the set $\{x \mid f(x) \le \alpha\}$. Could someone refresh me on how such a claim is achieved?

Updates:
The context is: a function $f$ is coercive if and only if for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x \mid f(x) \leq \alpha \}$ is compact.

Comment: What does "closeness of the set $\{x\}$" mean?

Comment: What space to start with?

Comment: Edited and added more contexts. Hope this would clarify some of the ambiguity.

Comment: No, it's still rather unclear. What does the "coercive" definition have to do with the rest of the question? Can you show us the proof you were looking at? (Either a reference or an image)

Comment: @arkeet Added the link for your reference.

Comment: OK, that entirely changes the meaning of the question. (Closeness and close**d**ness are rather different, and $\{x\}$ is a one-element set, which is not what's in your link.) I'll go ahead and edit to make the question clearer.

Comment: A function is continuous iff the preimage of an open set is always open, or equivalently if the preimage of a closed set is always closed (proving it's equivalent is almost immediate given that the complement of a closed set is open and vice versa). That's the definition. Now, what is $\{x\,|\,f(x)\leq \alpha\}$, in terms of preimage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preimage of any closed set is closed under a continuous map.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see that the set $\{x \mid f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is closed is that it is the preimage by $f$ of the closed subset $(-\infty,\alpha]$ of $\mathbb{R}$. (Remember that in general, if $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous and $A \subseteq Y$ is closed, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed.)

Alternatively, you could show that for any convergent sequence $(x^\nu)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(x^\nu) \le \alpha$ for all $\nu$, you would see that $f(\lim_{\nu\to\infty} x^\nu) = \lim_{\nu\to\infty} f(x^\nu) \le \alpha$ (where the equality holds by continuity of $f$).

Comment: But what about this question tells you that $f(x)$ is closed, though?  If you know that $f(x)$ is closed, then I could understa?d why, from the theorem you cited would allow us to say that $\{x|f(x) \le \alpha \}$ is closed.  But otherwise, how can you draw that conclusion?